# Get product image by its "Role" in the gallery

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, gallery, role

On the products grid in the **category view** I need to display additional image for some products.
When I have a gallery of product images:

```
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach ($images as $item)
{
    //...
}
```

how to retrieve an image by its **role** in the gallery? For example, I'd like to get the **image which is marked with the** `Thumbnail` **role** (or with some other custom role).

Is there any way to do that?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**You can get products image by Type by following Code :**

```
  $baseImage  = $product->getImage();
  $smallImage = $product->getSmallImage();
  $thumbnail  = $product->getThumbnail();
```

***OR* You can get types of gallery images of a product by following code:**

```
  $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();

  foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $entry) {
      $entry->getTypes();
  }
```

***OR* If you have custom media role then :**

```
  $customIcon = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_media_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Comment: And what if I have a custom role (when I created a custom attribute with Input Type `Media Image`)? How to get image of custom role?

Comment: @zitix See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get image URL like on frontend then you can use this code. I'm not sure that is a best solution but it works for me.))

```
use Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product as ProductResource;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as ImageHelper;

...

public function __construct(
    StoreManagerInterface     $storeManager,        
    ProductResource           $productResource,
    Emulation                 $appEmulation,
    ImageHelper               $imageHelper,
)
{
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;        
    $this->productResource = $productResource;
    $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
    $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
}

/**
 * @param $product
 * @param $imageCustomRole
 * @return string
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getCustomRoleImageUrl($product, $imageCustomRole)
{
    //Start frontend emulation for avoiding wrong path
    $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(), Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
    
    //getting image relative path if it is needed
    $img = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($imageCustomRole)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

    $result = '';
 
    if($img) {
        $productImageAttr = $product->getCustomAttribute($imageCustomRole);
        $productImage = $this->imageHelper->create()->init($product, $imageCustomRole)
            ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());
        $result = $productImage->getUrl();
    }
    
    //Stop frontend emulation
    $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
  
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On magento 2.4.6, the following code worked for me:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor;
.....
/** @var Processor */
protected Processor $processor;
.....
public function __construct(
.....
Processor $processor,
.....
){
.....
$this->processor = $processor;
.....
}

public function myCustomFancyMethod($sku)
{
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    $fullPath = $this->getMyImages();
    for ($i=0;$i < count($fullPath); $i++){
        $this->processor->addImage($product, $fullPath[$i], null, false, false);
    }

    $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();

    $i = 0;
        foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $entry) {
            $file = $entry->getFile();
            $product->setStoreId(0);
            if ($i === 0){
                $product->setImage($file);
                $product->setSmallImage($file)->setThumbnail($file);
            }
            $product->setData(
                'media_gallery',
                [
                    'images' => [
                        [
                            'file' => $file,
                            'position' => $i,
                            'label' => 'LabelName-'.$i,
                            'disabled' => 0,
                            'media_type' => 'image'
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            )->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
            $product->save();

            $i++;
        }
}
```

This will set the **thumbnail** and **base image** for the first image iterated.
Of course the method: `$this->getMyImages();` , I will let you to get from whereever you want the image paths.

I hope my post helped someone!

Good luck !